# Como separar e identificar objetos dentro de uma requisição Ajax, com dados vindos do Servlet via Json?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, servlet

Como faço para separar os objetos dentro do `Ajax`? O `Servlet` envia uma lista de objetos ao `Ajax`, mas não consigo separa-los dentro do `Ajax` para poder pegar um atributo de um objeto específico, por exemplo.

SERVLET

```
String op = request.getParameter("option");

if(op.equals("Car")){
    try{ 

        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();  
        JSONObject responseObj = new JSONObject();

        CarDAO d = new CarDAO();
        List<Car> procedimentos = d.listarCar();

        for(Car obj : procedimentos){

            JSONObject js = new JSONObject();
            double mst = obj.getValor();
            String data = obj.getData();
            String nome = obj.getNome();
            double avg = obj.getNome();

            if(nome.contains("KAL_69KV")){

                js.put("jsonKAL_69KV_percent",avg);
                js.put("jsonKAL_69KV", mst);
                js.put("json_KAL_69KV_Nome", ponto);
                js.put("json_KAL_69KV_Data", data);

            jsonArray.put(js);

            }else if(nome.contains("KCM_23KV")){
                String ponto = "KCM 23KV - CAMPO BOM 23KV";

                js.put("jsonKAL_69KV_percent",avg); 
                js.put("jsonKCM_23", mst);
                js.put("json_KCM_23_Nome",ponto);
                js.put("json_KCM_23_Data", data);
                jsonArray.put(js);
            }                    
        }               

        responseObj.put("jsonArray", jsonArray);
        out.print(responseObj);

    }catch (JSONException e){  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }  
...
...
```

Ajax

```
$j.ajax({
    data: {
        'option': "Car"
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    url: './GetDados',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {

        queryObject = eval('(' + JSON.stringify(data) + ')');

        queryObjectLen = queryObject.jsonArray.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < queryObjectLen; i++) {

            //----------------------------------------------------
            get data from object 1.name
            get data from object 1.age
            get data from object 1.anotherValue
            //----------------------------------------------------

            //----------------------------------------------------
            get data from object 2.name
            get data from object 2.age
            get data from object 2.anotherValue
            //----------------------------------------------------

            //----------------------------------------------------
            get data from object 3.name
            get data from object 3.age
            get data from object 3.anotherValue
            //----------------------------------------------------
            .
            .
            .
        }

        if (queryObjectLen === 0) {
            alert("No data!");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se `queryObject` estiver no formato JSON, vai ter uma estrutura `{key:value}`. Aí é só pegar com:

```
var value = queryObject['key'];
```

Se nao estiver, você pode user o `JSON.parse` primeiro:

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(objectToParse);
alert(parsed['key'])
```

1. Certifique-se que você está mandando um JSON do servlet como resposta. Dê um print antes de enviar e confirme.
2. Certifique-se que você está recebendo um JSON no AJAX ou transforme em um. Dê um print ao receber e confirme.

O seu `for` não se faz necessário.